cant open capacitor app in dev mode for physical device android using quasar but works on emulator
Im using Quasar and capacitor. I started a brand new project. Did build the app using:
quasar build -m capacitor -T android

I then open android studio. Using an emulator with API Tiramisu and the app do open.
I then change to my physical device ín developer mode. Also using Android 14 (tiramsiu). But the app seems to freeze. Nothing happens. After a while connection times out. I have tried on different devices with the same result.
variables.gradle:

minSdkVersion = 23 
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34


using java 17
gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.2.1-all.zip
networkTimeout=10000
validateDistributionUrl=true
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

package.json:
"quasar": "^2.16.0"
"vue": "^3.4.18"
"@quasar/app-vite": "^1.9.0",

and package.json in src-capacitor:
"dependencies": {
    "@capacitor/android": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/app": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@capacitor/core": "^6.0.0"
  }

what else can be relevant? Any hint of what to do?
UPDATE:
Once i connected my phone and computer to the same network it worked as expected.
